# Flutter - handling logic part

Tags: android, ios, dart, cross-platform, flutter

Let's consider this use case:

I have an already developed app in android and iOS which is out here for a while. I would like to implement a library/package in Flutter that could run on Android and iOS projects. Let's say I want to store some data in the flutter part, trigger some events, and so on. I might not want to show any screen from flutter just a logic part would be here. Is it currently possible to do something like that? Just to reduce the effort to implement it natively in iOS and Android